# Is there a way to get the source code filename and line number in Go?

Tags: debugging, go

In C/C++ you can use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to get access to the current file and line number.

Does Go provide something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed it does:

http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller

`runtime.Caller` can also be used to get the file name/line number of calling functions, too.